# How to differ between lowercase, uppercase, and signs in java

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I'm trying to build a program that can differ between if the users input is lowercase, uppercase, or a sign like(!, ?, *, /). Any ideas on how i could build such a program?

Here is what i have so far

[image: Here is what i have so far]

Comment: show us your effort

Comment: all you provide is a vague description. what have you got yourself so far?

Comment: don't put your code/results in an external link, please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
boolean isEntirelyUppercase(String s)
{
    return s.toUpperCase().equals(s);
}

boolean isEntirelyLowercase(String s)
{
    return s.toLowerCase().equals(s);
}

boolean isPunctuationMark(String s)
{
    if(s.length() != 1)
        return false;
    char c = s.charAt(0);
    return !Character.isLetterOrDigit(c);
}
```